# Diameter of binary tree recursively using the height of tree?

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

I want to calculate the diameter of a binary tree for which I have made a getDiameter() function. Now in this function I need to call the findHeight() function of Binary Tree which returns the height of binary tree. The 2 functions to calculate height in code1 and code2 are little different in terms of concept.
In code1 I am considering the height of a tree with single node(only root) is 1 and in code2 I am considering the height of the tree with single node is 0. So in the base case of code1 I have returned 0 and in code2 I have returned -1. I am confused which code is correct to be used code1 or code2 because the answer of diameter will vary ....

```
public static int getDiameter(BinaryTreeNode root) {        
    if (root == null)
        return 0;

    int rootDiameter = findHeight(root.getLeft()) + findHeight(root.getRight()) + 1;
    int leftDiameter = getDiameter(root.getLeft());
    int rightDiameter = getDiameter(root.getRight());

    return Math.max(rootDiameter, Math.max(leftDiameter, rightDiameter));
}


code1

public static int findHeight(BinaryTreeNode node) {
    if(node == null)
        return 0;
    else {
        return 1+Math.max(findHeight(node.left), findHeight(node.right));
    }

}
Code 2

public static int findHeight(BinaryTreeNode node) {
    if(node == null)
        return -1;
    else {
        return 1+Math.max(findHeight(node.left), findHeight(node.right));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Both the concepts in code 1 and code 2 are correct to find the height of a binary tree.

The point is that you have to be consistent with the `getDiameter()` function for the 2 different codes.

So, if code 1 is used the `getDiameter()` function will be :

```
public static int getDiameter(BinaryTreeNode root) {        

if (root == null)
    return 0;

int rootDiameter = findHeight(root.getLeft()) + findHeight(root.getRight()) + 1;
int leftDiameter = getDiameter(root.getLeft());
int rightDiameter = getDiameter(root.getRight());

return Math.max(rootDiameter, Math.max(leftDiameter, rightDiameter));

}
```

and if code 2 is used the `getDiameter()` function will be :

```
public static int getDiameter(BinaryTreeNode root) {        
if (root == null)
    return 0;

int rootDiameter = findHeight(root.getLeft()) + findHeight(root.getRight()) + 3;
int leftDiameter = getDiameter(root.getLeft());
int rightDiameter = getDiameter(root.getRight());

return Math.max(rootDiameter, Math.max(leftDiameter, rightDiameter));

}
```

Now the answer of diameter in both the cases will be correct.....